# Working along with digital clock

Tags: c++, time, clock

the following program which is a simple digital clock
i want the time to be continuously synchronized with the system time and display it on the top of the console without letting it interfere with my other work as in this case you can see that "hello" on 4th last line is never printed as the while loop above it never ends and also screen is cleared on every loop.

i want my code to perform instructions outside while loop also but
it never reaches at that point because the while loop never ends in this program

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{


 bool loop = true;


 while (loop)
 {


   time_t now = time ( 0 );
   tm *local = localtime ( &now );

    local->tm_hour -= 6;

    system("cls");
    cout << ctime ( &now ) <<'\n';
    cout<<"check";
    Sleep(1000);


 }
 cout<<"hello";//this is not printed as while loop doesnt ends
  cin.get();

  return 0;


}
```

Comment: Don't see how that is feasible.  Even if you could run a clock asynchronously (which you could do in a different thread), You are constantly clearing the console, so how can you see any other input/output stream?

Comment: is there any other alternative in which i can perform other instructions also with time displayed on top?

Comment: Remember that the duration for sleeping is usually a minimum and not accurate.  For example, the processor could sleep for 1030ms instead of 1000ms; as it has met the minimum requirements of 1000ms.

Comment: Life would be easier if you found an existing app or widget that does this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the loop isn't ending is that you aren't ending it.
You set `loop` to true at the beginning, and are looping as long as it remains true. However, you never actually set it to false.

If your goal is to create a clock that runs in the top of the command line, it will be sort of difficult, but not impossible.

Essentially, what you'll have to do is use a formatting library like [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) to constantly position your cursor on the line you want to print the time to, clear the line using [`clrtoeol`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xcurses/clrtoeol.html), print the time, then set the cursor back to the last line. You'll also have to put something in the main loop that takes the user's input and sends it to the shell interpreter, like this:

```
std::string command;
cin >> command;
system(command.c_str());
```

Overall, though, it might be easier to use the unix `date` command, like this:

```
date "%H:%M:%S"
```

Every time you need to know what time it is.

Comment: I don't think he is running a unix based OS, (It appears that he is including the windows header.) The DOS date command is explained at: http://www.computerhope.com/datehlp.htm . According to this "date /T" would accomplish the same result.

Comment: i am using windows operating system, windows 8 actually